How do I fix my ASP.NET/Nginx backend to not require the UserAgent header?
I have a project with a C# client and a C# (ASP.NET Web API) backend. Earlier this year the client was able to talk to the backend without specifying a User-Agent HTTP header, but at some point this mysteriously stopped working, and I was only able to fix it after much experimentation, by specifying a User-Agent header in the client.
Unfortunately I have a 2nd client which I don't control, which needs to talk to my backend. It was also working and is also now failing and I'm guessing it's because it doesn't specify the User-Agent.
The error I get in both cases is "An error occurred while sending the request.", inner exception “The response ended prematurely.". (Well I'm guessing as to the inner exception in the case of the client I don't control). To be clear, I don't get any HTTP status code - the server is not returning a well-formed HTTP response at all (does this confirm it's a bug in the web server?)
The backend is running on Nginx in a docker container on a Linux host. I don't know which level is requiring User-Agent.
How can I modify my backend to not require User-Agent?

I'm very sure the api's work fine by default without a user agent. At least all mine do and the external ones i have to contact and have no control over do also. Maybe a firewall issue? Also many bots don't use a user agent to they could be trying to block bots.

Have you got a chance to look at server logs? There must be something about particular user request being handled with non-200 status.

@AlexSeleznyov I don't get an HTTP response code at all. I don't get a well formed HTTP response. I think this means it's a bug in Nginx, right?

Start with server logs - it should have some information on what caused this behaviour. Once i had an issue with SSL library in java so nginx did not get full request hence was just closing connection with no response. Server logs helped to identify that.
